# How can I convert Telegram Session String from Telegram Session file

Tags: telegram-bot, pyrogram

I'm trying to get the Session String from an existing Session File of Pyrogram. How can I do that?

Can you help me?

```py
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from pyrogram import Client


config = dotenv_values(dotenv_path='./.env')


app = Client(
    # name="withstring",
    name="my_bot",
    # api_id=config.get("API_ID"),
    # api_hash=config.get("API_HASH"),
    bot_token=config.get("BOT_TOKEN"),
)

with app:
    app.send_message("username", text="Hello world Minhaz!")
    s = app.export_session_string()
    # print(s)
app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

The Session File is an sqlite database storing your authorization against the API and peers you've met (messages received, chats joined, etc).

To get the Session String to authenticate in Memory (losing peers when you log in again), you can just call the [`Client.export_session_string()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/export_session_string) method.

> Edit to add: If you already have a session file, you can use its name to log in, instead of creating a new in-memory session. If you have a `my_account.session` file, use `Client("my_session")` when instantiating your Client.

```py
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(":memory:")

with app:
    session = app.export_session_string()
    print(session)
```